# Which is more appropriate here: multiplicative or additive error?

Tags: numerical-methods

I am a beginner in numerical analysis and i have the following question at hand, but I am not being able to draw a logical conclusion: please help..

For estimating numerical errors in the process of evaluating $x\times y$ in ﬂoating-point arithmetic,
which of the following models would you choose to represent the error? Justify your answer.

Model 1 : We will assume that evaluating $ x\times  y$ on the computer outputs $(1 + \epsilon)(x \times y)
$
for some number  $\epsilon $ satisfying $0\le |\epsilon| \le \epsilon_{max} << 1$, where $\epsilon $ may depend upon $x,y$.

Model 2 : We will assume that evaluating $ x\times  y$ on the computer outputs $\epsilon+(x \times y)
$
for some number  $\epsilon $ satisfying $0\le |\epsilon| \le \epsilon_{max} << 1$, where $\epsilon $ may depend upon $x,y$.

Comment: Hint: what's `(x+e)*(y+e)` and which of the above models is that closest to for small values of e?

Comment: @barrycarter : in one case it comes $\epsilon=( x+y)e$ and in another case$\epsilon =(x+y)/(xy) *e$. So what to deduce from here?

Comment: There shouldn't be two cases. I'm using `e` to mean epsilon above. It should just be a single multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model of choice depends on whether we are working with normal or subnormal floating point numbers. If we are working with normal floating point numbers, then
\begin{equation}
\text{fl} (x \, \text{op} \,y) = (x \, \text{op} \, y)(1 + \delta)
\end{equation}
provided that the operation does not overflow or underflow. Here $\text{op}$ denotes one of the basic arithmetic operations and the absolute value of $\delta$ is less than the unit round off error $u$. However, are we concerned about subnormal floating point numbers, then the model changes to
\begin{equation}
\text{fl} (x \, \text{op} \,y) = (x \, \text{op} \, y)(1 + \delta) + \eta
\end{equation}
provided that the operation does not overflow. If your machines follows the IEEE standard and does gradual underflow to zero, you have
\begin{equation}
|\eta| \leq u \cdot (\text{underflow threshold}).
\end{equation}
The underflow threshold is the smallest positive normal floating point number.

Comment: Can you mathematically explain why model 1 is better than model 2?

Comment: These are the IEEE standard models for floating point arithmetic. Chips are built to conform to them. The first model I mentioned is useless in the face of underflow and you have to use the second model I mentioned.

Comment: You should consider the case of two positive floating point numbers $x$ and $y$ which are so small that $x\cdot y$ is rounded to $0$. Since the relative error is 1, you can not use the first model. You have have to use the second model.